Virtual environment marked as externally managed environemnt
I know that this error should be raised normally, but I am already working in a virtual environment, where the error should not be raised.
I created and activated a virtual environment on my Raspberry pi 4 so that I could install packages. It has been working fine. Seemingly randomly, I am getting the "This environment is externally managed..." error with the venv active. I disconnected the internet and tried a pip install on the system python, and that tried to work. The only thing I can think of as a possible cause was adding the activate command to the end of the .bashrc file, but it was running fine like this for weeks. How do I recover my virtual environment and restore the protections to the system python install?

This question is similar to: How do I solve "error: externally-managed-environment" every time I use pip 3?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Woodford, it is different because I already made and activated the virtual environment. I'm running pip from the virtual environment, not the system python install.

Can you give an example, with your pip install command, the error message, and probably a echo $VIRTUAL_ENV or similar statement?

"adding the activate command to the end of the .bashrc file,": I can't tell you exactly why, but that does sound as a not-so-good idea.

"How do I recover my virtual environment and restore the protections to the system python install": that's unclear what you mean? How is your v-env not there anymore? The directory will still exist. The system protections should also still exist, so what did you do with that "pip install on the system python" that you think it didn't; Did you use sudo?

The answer(s) in the question linked explains why you might see that message (because you're not actually in a venv). In your case I would assume that your venv isn't being applied like you expected (e.g. your PATH is being modified somewhere after .bashrc is sourced). Does which pip and which python point to your venv directory?

I ran all of the commands inside of the virtual environment (.venv).
After running pip install numpy  I get the error error: externally-managed-environment
running echo $VIRTUAL_ENV gives /home/raspberry/.venv
running which python gives /home/raspberry/.venv/bin/python
running which pip gives /home/raspberry/.venv/bin/pip
As far as not getting the error when outside of the virtual environment is concerned, I found that virtualenv was messing with the path and redirecting to its own directory. Uninstalling it fixed the issue with pip protection in the global space.
